# Convert SQL to Active Record Query matching on IN

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How would I convert this sort of SQL into Active Record Syntax.
I've struggled mainly resolving the IN with the other elements.

`SELECT \"accounts\".* FROM account_categories, accounts WHERE \"accounts\".\"worksheet_id\" = 5 AND (account_categories.name IN ('Savings','Deposit') AND account_categories.id = accounts.account_category_id) ORDER BY \"accounts\".\"id\" ASC"`

*worksheet_id will vary, won't always be 5.*

I want to use this in a scope in the Account model.
Similar like this

`scope :savings, -> { from('account_categories, accounts').where("account_categories.name = ? AND account_categories.id = zen_accounts.account_category_id", 'Savings') }`

but testing for both Savings & Deposit something like this:

`scope :savings_and_deposit, -> { from('account_categories, accounts').where("account_categories.name = ? AND account_categories.id = zen_accounts.account_category_id", ['Savings','Deposit]) }`

Comment: Your last example where you query across both names doesn't works? Which error you get? And you missed `['Savings','Deposit]` closing quote here.

Comment: @Evolve : Why don't you use `account_categories.name in (?) ` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
scope :savings, -> (worksheet_id) { filtered_categories(worksheet_id, ['Savings']) }
scope :savings_and_deposit, -> (worksheet_id) { filtered_categories(worksheet_id, ['Savings', 'Deposit']) }

scope :filtered_categories, -> (worksheet_id, category_names) do 
  joins(:account_categories).
  where(worksheet_id: worksheet_id).
  where(account_categories: {name: category_names}).
  order(id: :asc)
end
```

This code supposes what `Account` model already has relation `account_categories`, otherwise replace `joins(:account_categories)` with `joins("JOIN account_categories ON account_categories.id = accounts.account_category_id")`